# Stripping a character only once in python

Tags: python, string, strip

I am parsing values from a file, some of which can be string literals, enclosed in double quotes. To get the actual value I have to strip the double quotes:

```
>>> raw_value = r'"I am a string"'
>>> processed_value = raw_value.strip('"')
>>> print(processed_value)
I am a string
```

However, some values contain escaped double quotes, which can be at the end:

```
>>> raw_value = r'"Simon said: \"Jump!\""'
>>> processed_value = raw_value.strip('"')
>>> print(processed_value)
Simon said: \"Jump!\
```

You see my problem here: the escaped double quote is stripped away which leaves an orphaned double quote when I write the file back and makes it unreadable. I could do:

```
def unique_strip(some_str):

    beginning = 1 if some_str.startswith('"') else 0
    end = -1 if some_str.endswith('"') and some_str[-2] != "\\" else None
    return some_str[beginning:end]
```

Using previous example:

```
>>> unique_strip(raw_value)
'Simon said: \\"Jump!\\"'
>>> raw_value = r'"Simon said: \"Jump!\"'
>>> unique_strip(raw_value)
'Simon said: \\"Jump!\\"'
```

So now it even works if the trailing double quote is missing. Is there a more pythonic way to do this, using built-in `strip` for example ? If not, is there anything wrong or any loophole in my method ?

---

**Update**

I guess my function raises `IndexError` for an input like `some_str = '"'`. So maybe:

```
def unique_strip(some_str):

    beginning = 1 if some_str.startswith('"') else 0
    end = -1 if len(some_str) > 1 and some_str.endswith('"') and some_str[-2] != "\\" else None
    return some_str[beginning:end]
```

Comment: This looks like a job for `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: @PM2Ring That would be painfully slow as compared to direct string manipulation. Besides, it would break if the string isn't wrapped with double quotes on the inside.

Comment: You can have a look at `re.sub` with look arounds.

Comment: You can `str.replace` the \" to something not occurred in your string, `strip`, then replace back

Comment: @jf328 This feels a bit far-fetched, and from the top of my head I can imagine many scenarios where replacing it back could be hazardous unless you replace it with something horribly long like "ESCAPEDDOUBLEQUOTE" or something...

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Mmh using `re` feels like swatting a fly with a sledgehammer, but I guess that's its purpose... What regexp would you propose to use in my `re.sub` ?

Comment: @ValentinB., nothing wrong with "ESCAPEDDOUBLEQUOTE12138". You can chain the operation together and never care about the intermediate result.

Comment: @jf328 "if it's stupid but it works it's not stupid" might be applicable here indeed. Post an answer with it ! Don't know if I'll accept it but I will definitely upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest but not the safest way is to replace the `\"` with some string that will not occur elsewhere. Then strip, and replace back.

```
raw_value = r'"Simon said: \"Jump!\""'

IMPOSSIBLE_STR = '\\"3'
raw_value.replace('\\"', IMPOSSIBLE_STR).strip('"').replace(IMPOSSIBLE_STR,'\\"')
Out[102]: 'Simon said: \\"Jump!\\"'
```

I suppose it's very unlikely to have `\"` followed by a number.

Regex will probably solve the problem better, conditioned on that you write the correct regex!

Comment: "I suppose it's very unlikely to have `\"` followed by a number.". It is possible in my context, so I went with a rather long intermediate replacement instead. I have implemented it and it works, so if noone comes up with a magical regex or a better looking solution I will accept yours.

Comment: @ValentinB. Just don't blame me if your rocket explodes. :)